# Show whitespaces in dropdown list in razor page

Tags: sql, razor, asp.net-core

I have a query in SQL that return the name of my organizations with whitespaces [Sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxlk4.png).

In my asp net core project i need to show in a dropdown list all the organizations retaining whitespaces.

```
    <form method="get" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Организация</label>
        <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-size="7" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@Model.Organizations, "Id", "Name"))" asp-for="FilterModel.OrganizationKey">
            <option value="">Show Organizations</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

My code shows the organizations w/o spaces. How can achieve that? Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using an Option Group within the select? See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms#the-select-tag-helper) for details. Search for 'option group' on the page.

Comment: Hi. I cannnot use option group because my main organization is also used to retrieve data from another query. I dont want to remake my stored procedures. Maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may replace spaces in strings to `\xA0`.

This will produce `&nbsp;` during page rendering and so the user will see this as spaces.